# Python/Keras - using the fit function for a model : No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a neural network program based on the imageset data set to recognize simple pictures such as a white square on a black background.
I therefore used keras' fit function on the model once I created the simple images, and I had this error : No gradients provided for any variable

here is the code.

```
size_img=100
nb_img=30

for n in range(nb_img):
    horiz=np.sort(np.random.rand(2)*size_img).astype(int)
    vert=np.sort(np.random.rand(2)*size_img).astype(int)
    shade_dark=np.random.rand()*100 #between 0 and 100
    shade_light=np.random.rand()*100 + 155 #between 155 and 255
    
    
    img = np.zeros(shape = (size_img, size_img)).astype('uint8') + int(shade_dark)
    img[horiz[0]:horiz[1], vert[0]:vert[1]] = shade_light
    
    mask = np.zeros(shape = (size_img, size_img)).astype('uint8')
    mask[horiz[0]:horiz[1], vert[0]:vert[1]] = 1

    for i in range(size_img):
        for j in range(size_img):
            img[i][j] = img[i][j]# + np.random.normal(0, 7)
    
    
    img=Image.fromarray(img, 'L')
    mask=Image.fromarray(mask, 'L')
    img.save('/Users/william/Desktop/rectangles'+str(n)+'.png')
    mask.save('/Users/william/Desktop/mask'+str(n)+'.png')
```

```
listx=[0 for i in range(nb_img)]
for n in range(nb_img):
    img_path = '/Users/william/Desktop/rectangles'+str(n)+'.png'
    imga = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    xn=np.expand_dims(imga, axis=0)
    xn = preprocess_input(xn)
    listx[n]=xn
listy=[0 for i in range(nb_img)]
for n in range(nb_img):
    mask_path = '/Users/william/Desktop/mask'+str(n)+'.png'
    imgb = image.load_img(mask_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    yn=np.expand_dims(imgb, axis=0)
    yn = preprocess_input(yn)
    listy[n]=yn
model.fit(listx[0],listy[0])
```

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
model.trainable=True
model.compile(loss = 'mean_absolute_error',optimizer='Adam')
```

Comment: Please add the code that builds your model.

Comment: It is included in the last 6 lines.